# react redux why use dispatch = useDispatch()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I followed the react-redux tutorial and the following pattern regularly appears in the example code:

```
import { useDispatch} from 'react-redux'

...

const dispatch = useDispatch()
```

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-3-data-flow#adding-new-posts

What is the purpose of redeclaring the dispatch function like this?

I looked at the react-redux code and (I think?) the hook factory returns a function. So is the purpose of redeclaring the dispatch hook to use it as a function expression instead of a function declaration for performance?

Why is this not done for the `useSelector` hook?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the linked page where they call `useSelector` without passing in a selector... Can you be more specific about where you're seeing this?

Comment: It's in the features/posts/AddPostForm section, which is the final code section prior to "What you have learned".

Comment: Sorry, in that code snippet it is const dispatch = useDispatch(), the same pattern is used for useSelector elsewhere

Comment: `const dispatch = useDispatch()` This is the standard usage of the useDispatch hook. The purpose of that hook is just to return the dispatch function. What you described for useSelector is not the way the useSelector hook is designed to be used, and i still don't see it anywhere.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I wanted to know why const dispatch = useDispatch() is used, or const history = useHistory(). I've edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to know why const dispatch = useDispatch() is used, or const history = useHistory()

That's just the way those hooks are designed. The job of these hooks is "please give me the dispatch function" and "please give me the history object" respectively. It's a way of getting a dependency into your component without passing it in as a prop. So all these hooks do is return that piece of data, and then your component can use it from there as it sees fit.

Comment: I see, thanks. I thought they were the same as useSelector but I understand the difference now I think

Answer (score 0):

The useSelector hook is a hook which makes it possible to access the Redux store in function component. You can pass a function to the useSelector to access the correct values from your store. Lets say your store looks something likes this:

```
{ auth: 
    { user: 
        {firstName, lastName }
    }
}
```

If you would like to access the firstName of a user in your function component you can use the useSelector function like this:

```
const firstName = useSelector(state => state.auth.user.firstName);
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was clear. I know you can use the selector as you explained but that isn't what I was asking. The following appears in the example code:   const selector = useSelector()     then, to follow your example, something like     const firstName = selector(auth.user.firstName)